# Real-time update from json

Tags: d3.js

**EDIT:** I have rephrased the whole question to make it more readable. Since I found out how to make it work, the code now shows the working solution.

**My question was: **

- I would like to use d3 to visualise a graph.
- The data for the graph is created by a Python script and then exported to a *.json file.
- Every second I would like the Python script to update the *.json and then d3 to read the *.json again and update the graph.
- How could I make this work?

**My solution is: **

```js
// Update function to update the visualisation with new data

function update(links){
  
  // ...
  
  force
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .start();
  
  // ...
  
}

// The following function loads the JSON

function loadNewData(){

  d3.json("data/data.json", function(error, json){

    update(json);

});
  

// This function is just a timer to update the data every x milliseconds (normal JS)
  
setInterval(function () {

  loadNewData();
            

}, 3000);
```

Comment: What webserver are you using?  How are you serving the JSON?  How is the python script invoked?  Instead of having Python write a JSON file, and then serving that file to d3, just have Python handle the http request and return the JSON.

Comment: Thank you, Mark.

I am using a Monkey HTTP server on Ubuntu.
So far, I only have the Python script that is directly invoked via the console. It does not produce the JSON yet (this is still to be implemented) - currently I only create a Pandas Dataframe.

Do you have any suggestions of how I can update the graph every second or so?

Please let me know if I need to clarify my questions.

(I have updated my question to include the information you asked for.)

Comment: does your update function get called by setInterval?

Comment: Hi @andypopa, yes, that is correct.

But I cheat because in the line before that I replace the old dataset by the new one:

`dataset = dataset_update;`

The update function then just applies the new dataset to the graph. It's not a (near) real-time update and it's not read from an external *.json.